# Выравнивание галереи по центру?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

https://goreska.github.io/nlalmaty/
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Не могу спозиционировать блок с галереей на адаптиве, на десктопной версии выравнивал блок флексами, обернул его в wrap, и выравнял
    justify-content: center
, задав ширину обертки 100%, а ширину галереи 90%. Но на мобильной - ширина 575  - выравнивается в одну колонку с помощью

```
.grid-item 
left: 50% !important
transform: translateX(-50%)
```

Если адаптировать для разрешения 576 и выше - то при разрешении 768 например, 2 блока накладываются друг на друга, есть ли вариант выравнить их без танцев с бубном?

Comment: это кто вам такое делал ?

Comment: Как насчет того что бы на моб устройствах отключить плагин и просто выровнять блоки?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский я учусь, взял обычный сайт, и решил его сверстать по своему, но косяки с галереей, не посмотрел что она по умолчанию выстраивается по левому краю

Comment: @МаксимЛенский что-то не так с сайтом?

Comment: @Underdoggitвсё так как надо ....но этот фильтр надо адаптировать по другому как то ...

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Да вот сижу сам мозгую, оптимальный вариант никак не нахожу, кроме как создать 20 медиа запросов и выравнить блок с галереей в процентах отталкива от левого края,. но это говнокод...(, либо как посоветовал сверху EK, у меня на мобильном нет фильтра, и можно обрубить сам плагин на мобильных и просто выровнять блоки по центру силами флексов, а после появления фильтров на >976px подрубить его

Comment: там не только фильтр не адаптивен но и вся страница тоже уезжает

Comment: @МаксимЛенский на каком разрешении? Вроде смотрел, никаких дефектов кроме центровки фильтра не заметил

Comment: я скачал всю репу твою на github - посмотрю что можно сделать

Comment: @МаксимЛенский спасибо, буду очень благодарен

Comment: в общем у тебя overflay вылазиет за пределы родителя и  иза за этого смещается весь grid полностью

Comment: @МаксимЛенский гляну, скорее всего скриптом придется отключать плагин на разрешениях меньше 992px, и равнять блоки флексами, так будет адекватнее всего

Comment: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/26jq/y9HuTennX вот твой архив - я убрал mobile-hide и что то ещё не помню - если не дочёты какие то пиши

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Спасибо, гляну и отпишусь